# Java regex for parsing Qt localization functions params

Tags: java, regex, qt, greedy, localizable.strings

Qt has special functions for localization call.
Functions like `qsTr()`, `tr()`, `QT_TR_NOOP()`, `qsTranslate()`, etc.

I need to parse the content of above functions` calls params.

For example, `qsTr()`:

```
qsTr(string source, string disambiguation, int n)
```

There are just 3 possible calls for that function

```
qsTr("source")
qsTr("source", "disambiguation")
qsTr("source", "disambiguation", count) // count - some int value for source 
                                        // if it contains plurals - %n
```

Let's assume we found in source Qt or QML this line:

```
qsTr("source string")
```

For such a case, I have written a Java regex:

```
(?<=qsTr\\()(\\s*(\\".*?(?<\\\\)\\")?)(?=\\s*\\))
```

Above regex will exactly match "source string" and that is correct.

But I need a DOTALL regex, not just for single line.

One of possible problems is that we can find next call that is incorrect and we should ignore it:

```
qsTr("source", count)
```

The above regex will fail because of greedy quantifiers. It will look for next `"\\s*)"` down the whole text.
Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's possible to reach content between quotes and then seeking for ).

Pattern will look like

```
Pattern.compile("\\qsTr?\\s*\\(\\s*(((\".*?(?<!\\\\)\")|('.*?(?<!\\\\)')).*?)(?=\\))", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

It guarantees if content wrapped by qsTr() starts from " it will definetely be extracted.
For example if you to parse next string:

```
qsTr("source", count)
```

you'll get next result:

```
"source", count
```

And then you can check for validity of extracted string (for example, if it is possible for qsTr function to contain another params after static string param).